# Javascript multi Array operation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have come accross this strange use if javascript array 
Can anyone explain me this.

[1,2,3][1,2]

What type of operation is this ?

Comment: What's your exact question?

Comment: How are dealing with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the expression

```
var result = [1, 2, 3][1, 2]
```

The first part `[1, 2, 3]` is an array literal, the second part `[1, 2]` is an index into the array. So it's equivalent to:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3];
var index = (1, 2);
var result = array[index];
```

`(1, 2)` is a *comma expression*. It evaluates its arguments from left to right, and returns the value of the last one, so it's equivalent to just `2`. So the whole thing is equivalent to:

```
var result = array[2];
```

which sets `result` to `3`.

Comment: Just to clarify, the comma expression would return the right-most element, ie `(1,2,3)` would return `3`.

Comment: That's actually two comma expressions, equivalent to `((1, 2), 3)`, just as `1 + 2 + 3` is two addition expressions.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I understood ur explanation for index. but i didnt get ((1,2),3). 
Please explain me the use of comma opeartor

Comment: @Kpatel1989 These are binary operators, they take two arguments. If you used them multiple times in a row, they have to be grouped. So just as `1 + 2 + 3` is processed as `((1 + 2) + 3)`, `1, 2, 3` is processed as `((1, 2), 3)`. The value of `(1, 2)` is `2`, and `(2, 3)` is `3`, so `(1, 2, 3)` is `3`.